# Calling WCF then use JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, wcf

How can I call a WCF and put into the following method ? I have the service on http://kailun92wcf.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc of a getSearchCoords().

```
private void LoadJsonData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    //retrieving the results for the keywords the user input


    searchError.Text = "Loading... Please Wait";
    if (Classes.Global.searched == 1)
    {
        searchVal = new List<string>();
    }

    var service = new Service1Client();
    service.getSearchCoordsAsync(new getSearchCoordsRequest {searchBar.Text.ToString()});
    service.getSearchCoordsCompleted += new EventHandler<MyCloudService.getSearchCoordsCompletedEventArgs>(obj_getSearchCoordsCompleted);



 //        string data = @"{
    //
    //                         ""PageCount"" : ""1"",
    //                         ""SearchResults"": [
    //                            {
    //                                ""SEARCHVAL"": ""ORCHARD22"",
    //                                ""CATEGORY"": ""Building"",
    //                                ""X"": ""29483.4267"",
    //                                ""Y"": ""31269.938""
    //                            },
    //                            {
    //                                ""SEARCHVAL"": ""ORCHARDBELAIR"",
    //                                ""CATEGORY"": ""Building"",
    //                                ""X"": ""27071.2616"",
    //                                ""Y"": ""31629.2465""
    //                            }
    //                        ]
    //                    }";

    var pagedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestMap.Classes.Global.ResultSetPager<TestMap.Classes.Global.Place>>(data);

        //or lstPlaces
    Results.ItemsSource = pagedResults.SearchResults;
}
```

Need to put the json data from the svc into the result to display on my windows phone. How can I do it ?

Comment: this is actually continued from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322437/get-address-name-from-wcf-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your service is returning an "error" string for any search parameters.

```
 private void LoadJsonData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var service = new Service1Client();
        service.getSearchCoordsAsync(new getSearchCoordsRequest(searchBar.Text));
        service.getSearchCoordsCompleted += new EventHandler<getSearchCoordsCompletedEventArgs>(obj_getSearchCoordsCompleted);
    }

    public void obj_getSearchCoordsCompleted(object sender, getSearchCoordsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var response = e.Result.getSearchCoordsResult;
        var pagedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultSetPager<Place>>(response);
        lstPlaces.ItemsSource = pagedResults.SearchResults;
    }
```

Comment: I had this error Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Place' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: also this Error 2 The type or namespace name 'ResultSetPager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If i change the code to this <TestMap.Classes.Global.ResultSetPager<TestMap.Classes.Global.Place> I had werid results displayed on the listview like testmap.classes.global above each location name.

Comment: what does your XAML look likie? You are most likely not referencing a String / Int type, but an object like "Place" in your markup

Comment: Thanks a lot you are right, there is a button at xaml. Thanks !